# Why can't I execute this simple shell script?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a file called go in ~/

All I want to do is to be able to run go and have it cd to this other dir.

This is what the go file looks like:

```
$ cat go
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/rs3
```

I ran the line $ chmod +x go

And then the line ./go to attempt to run the file.

If i put echo whatever in the file it will print whatever to the console, but the cd command never works.

Thanks.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz cool, that pretty much answers the question, thanks! too bad none of the tutorials ive been looking at for 2 hours told me that.

Comment: @sherlock: You can still run `. ~/go` to change directory

Comment: The `cd` command in the script does work. It just applies only to the process running the script, not to its parent process (your interactive shell). You can use `.` to run the script in the context of your current shell (in which case the script probably *shouldn't* be executable and shouldn't have the `#!/bin/bash` line), *or* you can modify the script to print a `cd` command to standard output and then execute that command: `eval $(~/go)` (which you can wrap in a shell function for convenience).

Comment: In the latter case (`eval $(~/go)`), if it prints multiple commands they should be separated with semicolons, since `$(cmd)` joins the output of `cmd` into a single line.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the script runs in a subshell, so the environment is different.

What you *can* do is to `alias go='cd ~/Desktop/3s3'` - as it's an `alias`, the shell performs the substitution and runs the `cd` on itself, as if you've just typed it.

You should define the alias in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or any file that gets `source`d when you login.